# I'm getting key error: 'District' for the command df.groupby(["District"]).sum()[['TSP','TSPExp']].sort_values(['TSPExp'], ascending=[False]).head(3)

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

To find the effectiveness of fund utilization of TSPFund and TSPExp.

```
df['percent']=df['TotExp']/df['Tot']*100
df['percent'].head(14)
df.groupby(['District']).sum()[['percent']].sort_values(['percent'], ascending=[False]).head(14)


df.groupby(["District"]).sum()[['TSP','TSPExp']].sort_values(['TSPExp'], ascending=[False]).head(3)
```

I expect a tabular presentation with District, TSPExp and TSP as columns.
but I am shown `KeyError: 'District'`

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the column names of your data, I often face this kind of problem when reading from excel/csv, most of the cases column names from data contains preceding or ending white-space.